# Get Dictionary Value If User Inputs Equals Key

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to do the above by looping through my dictionary of about 80k items.  Right now it is pointing to the correct value if I leave the `else: print(does not exist.)` out of the code.  If I have the `else` in there it just endlessly prints the `else` code.  Here is the function in question:

```
def query_disease_to_code() :
    """ Interactive function to query code from disease name. """
    d = disease_to_code_dictionary() # disease to code dictionary

    query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
    while query != "q" :
        query = query.lower() # lowercase
        for key, value in d.items():
            if key == query:
                print(value)
            else:
                print("Disease name does not exist.")
        query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
        

query_disease_to_code()
```

Comment: Just use `v = d.get(key, None)` then test `if v is not None:`... etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
def query_disease_to_code():
    """ Interactive function to query code from disease name. """
    d = disease_to_code_dictionary()  # disease to code dictionary

    query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
    while query != "q":
        if query in d:
            print(d[query])
        else:
            print("Disease name does not exist.")
        query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
```

The reason that you are seeing endless `"Disease name does not exist."` is that you are iterating over all keys and every time `if key == query:` evals to `False` it falls to the else branch.

As an alternative you could also use [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), like follows:

```
query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
while query != "q":
    print(d.get(query, "Disease name does not exist."))
    query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
```

Comment: @SeanLawton Glad I could help

Comment: Can't click it for a few more minutes